# How to ignore a word in string while capturing with a regex in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, url

Here is what my code looks like:

```
preg_replace("/(test)/i", "<strong>$1</strong>", $text);
```

And here is an example string:

```
"<a href="www.website.com/search/%23test">#test</a>"
```

I want to capture the second 'test' but not the first one in the URL.

Comment: Is it always the second one?

Comment: I don't think this is a very good idea. What do you *actually* want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid matching something which is inside angular brackets (at least, if there are no literal angular brackets in the text) with a negative lookahead:

```
preg_replace("/test(?![^<>]*>)/i", "<strong>$0</strong>", $text);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hT8hM5)

Comment: @lokiloq What do you mean?

Comment: Why I can not do something like preg_replace("/(?!23>)test/i", "<strong>$0</strong>", $text); ? 
@Jerry

Comment: @lokiloq I'm not sure exactly what you are asking, but you should use `[^<>]*` to make sure there's no opening angular bracket before that closing angluar bracket, otherwise, it will match the second `test` as well. And it would be more efficient putting the negative lookahead after `test`, otherwise it will be checking `test` without any benefit whatsoever.